# How to fix app crashing after intent activity called

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to pass a variable from database(created on LoginActivity.java) when user pressing register button and pass the value to HomeActivity.java .Before I use intent extras and bundle, the code works fine(except passing the variable).  But after I put the new code, the app crash immediately after I press register button

Ive tried searching for another possible duplication question but none of them having the same problem as mine. Most of them forgot to put the activity in android manifest but I've put the LoginActivity on android manifest. And of course I've noticed there are no error on the code while compiling

This is the home activity

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;

Intent i = getIntent();

Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

String pname = extras.getString("P_NAME");
int pcoins = extras.getInt("P_COINS");
int pgems = extras.getInt("P_GEMS");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set fullscreen and no title//////////
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ////////////////////////////////////

    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    goProfileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilebutton);
    shopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shopbutton);
    goBarrackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barrackbutton);
    goDungeonBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dungeonbutton);
    goFarmBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.farmbutton);
    saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);

    NameTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName);
    CoinTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cointxt);
    GemTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gemtxt);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    ///////////////////////////////

    NameTxt.setText(pname);
    CoinTxt.setText("Coin: " + pcoins);
    GemTxt.setText("Gem: " + pgems);

    ///////// Button ///////////////////

    goProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent profileSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(profileSwitch);
        }
    });

    goFarmBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent farmSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(farmSwitch);
        }
    });

    shopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent shopSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), startGame.class);
            startActivity(shopSwitch);
        }
    });

    goBarrackBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent barrackSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), startBarrack.class);
            startActivity(barrackSwitch);
        }
    });

    goDungeonBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent dungeonSwitch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dungeonActivity.class);
            startActivity(dungeonSwitch);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("EXIT GAME");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setNegativeButton("NOT NOW",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
    alertdialog.show();
}
    }
```

And this is LoginActivity

```
EditText edit1;
EditText edit2;
EditText edit3;

Button registerBtn;
Button loginBtn;

DatabaseHelper myDb;

User player1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set fullscreen and no title//////////
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpname);
    edit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpemail);
    edit3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editppw);

    registerBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
    loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()) {
                String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
                String Password = edit3.getText().toString();
                User currentUser = myDb.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Email, Password));

                if (currentUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Successfull");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unsuccessfull");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()) {
                String UserName = edit1.getText().toString();
                String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
                String Password = edit3.getText().toString();

                if (!myDb.isEmailExists(Email)) {
                    player1 = new User(null, UserName, Email, Password);
                    myDb.addUser(player1);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("P_NAME", player1.getName());
                    extras.putInt("P_COINS", player1.getCoins());
                    extras.putInt("P_GEMS", player1.getGems());
                    i.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } 
        }
    });
}

public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = false;
    String Email = edit2.getText().toString();
    String Password = edit3.getText().toString();

    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
        valid = false;
        edit2.setError("Please enter valid email!");
    } else {
        valid = true;
        edit2.setError(null);
    }

    if (Password.isEmpty()) {
        valid = false;
        edit3.setError("Please enter valid password!");
    } else {
        if (Password.length() > 5) {
            valid = true;
            edit3.setError(null);
        } else {
            valid = false;
            edit3.setError("Password is to short!");
        }
    } 
    return valid;
}
```

I have cut some of the codes for the sake of readability

It supposed to pass the name, coins, and gems, data from the database into the variable in HomeActivity.but it seems my code crash the app

---

I've also snapshoted the logcat[image: Logcat snapshot from android device]

Comment: add the log cat where the error occurs

Comment: I'm sorry to say this. I'm editing my code directly from android device(non rooted) and I have trouble accessing logcat

Comment: @NikolaiAleksandrovsk you don't need rooted device for accessing logcat

Comment: Oh is it.. I've got something on the logcat. Something like this

Comment: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically try this, i use it for editing android apps from a mobile device and still be able to see logs

Comment: That one is useful. I'm glad that someone recommended me that code. And also sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you ask the Activity for `getIntent` before onCreate is called.

Try this:

```
Intent i;
Bundle extras;

String pname; 
int pcoins;
int pgems; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    i = getIntent();
    extras = i.getExtras();

    pname = extras.getString("P_NAME");
    pcoins = extras.getInt("P_COINS");
    pgems = extras.getInt("P_GEMS");

    // follow with your onCreate code ....
}
```

Comment: Solved. It's fixed now. Thanks for that @Rafael T